# Xamarin Forms - prevent iOS storyboard from loading

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I'm using Visual Studio for Windows to test a Xamarin Forms app on Android. Now I want to test it on an iPhone as well, which is possible by connecting the iPhone to my Windows system and using [Xamarin Hot Restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart).
The app is deployed on the iPhone, but when I tap on the icon it starts for a brief moment and then it closes (like it crashes). Looking at the link sent here earlier, in the Limitations section, the cause of this issue might be described there:

"Storyboard and XIB files are not supported and the app may crash if it attempts to load these at runtime. Use the HOTRESTART preprocessor symbol to prevent this code from executing."

I do have a Storyboard and I think an XIB file, but I have no idea how to prevent it from loading. The storyboard is called in info.plist only and the XIB extension is called in the .storyboard file.

**LaunchScreen.storyboard**

[image]

**Info.plist**

[image]

The usage of the preprocessor symbol HOTRESTART is only for C# I believe. My question thus is: how can I use the processor symbol HOTRESTART to prevent the loading of storyboard and XIB files?

Comment: Please do not posts code as images

Comment: Did it work well if just using a default template?

Comment: No. There is a storyboard in there as well.

Comment: I found a similar issue on Github,  which seems nothing to do with storyboard. Could it be help: [Xamarin Hot Restart - Default template app crashes on startup](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13759)